# Iterating over Column object of a dataframe in a UDF function and store data during iteration in a dictionary

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm new to PySpark and UDF.

I have a dataframe and I want to iterate over multiple columns (Each column in original DF is Column object) and use a UDF to store data in a dictionary. I have written the below code, but nothing gets stored in the dictionary.

Can anyone help me understand what's the issue here? I don't care about the return value. I will be dropping the whole column. I want data in three columns mapped and added to dictionary.

```
dictionary= {}
def add_descriptions(in_dict):
    def f(x, y, z):
        if x not in in_dict:
            in_dict[x] = {
                z : {
                    "data" : y
            }}
        else:
            in_dict[x].update({
                z: {
                    "data" : y
            }})
        return "Hello World"
    return udf(f)

updated_data = df.withColumn(
    "description",
    add_descriptions(dictionary)(col("valueA"), col("valueB"), col("valueC"))
)
```

Edit : Made code more resembling to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The issue is that UDFs are not executed in the same Python process where they are defined. They might not even be executed on the same *machine*. Each Python function has its own "scope" containing its associated variables, but there's no way to synchronize those scopes across separate unconnected processes, virtual machines, or physical nodes in a cluster.

Comment: You can try instead creating an RDD of dictionaries, and ["folding"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.fold.html) or ["reducing"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.reduce.html) that RDD down into a single value.  I haven't used Spark in a while, so I will leave it to someone else to build a coherent answer based on this suggestion.

Comment: @shadowtalker thank you for suggestion. Currently, I have decided to just convert the whole data to pandas and run normal python function.
I have decided to refactor this code when I'm more comfortable with PySpark and UDFs.

Comment: In general, if you can do it in Pandas or some other non-Spark solution, you should. Distributed computing in general should be something you resort to when single-node computing won't work, not a default first choice. If you need to handle bigger datasets that still fit in memory on a single machine, consider using Polars instead of Pandas.